# jQuery 1.3.2 validate help

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using the jQuery validate plugin to validate my inputs in a form.

The problem is that when a field is mandatory it shows this:

```
This field is required.
```

Instead I would like to show a little icon just after the input, replacing that `This field is required.`

This is the code I am using:

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submForm').validate({ 
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // Do cleanup first
            $('input:text[value=\"\"]', '#submForm').remove();
            var serialized = $('#submForm').serialize();
             $.get('".$site['url']."modules/yobilab/copyright/classes/DO_submission.php', serialized);
            window.setTimeout('location.reload()', 8000);
            return false;
            form.submit(); 
        }
    })
});
```

Could you help me please?

Thank you!

Comment: Well there is a `;` missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#form').validate({
    rules: {
        field1: { required: true } },
    messages: {
        field1: { required : "Message that shows when required field isnt filled"} },
    submitHandler: {
        // whatever } 
});
```

Use the plug-in like this in order to have easier message / rule placement.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation <- check the possible rules and whatnot here. Not sure if the jquery version changes that much in this case.

EDIT: If you want to put an image instead of a message, you can just put the html code instead of the string message.

Ex:

```
field1: {
    required: "<img src='blabla.jpeg'>" }
```

Comment: The form is very big, I can not assign a rule for each field. That should be generic as it is in my code right now. I do not know how to properly add an image instead of plain text where the ruls says "messages", could you please provide the answer? Thank you

Comment: Where you input the message, place the html code for the image you wanna put it. Should show it just fine.

Comment: Ok but as far as I see it will work for a specific field. Since I have too many fields I would like to know a solution that will work any mandatory field, without the need to specificate a field. Is this possible?

Comment: Consider checking the "Refactoring Rules" section in the following link: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference or this post also might help: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/validation-multi-element-validation

Answer (score 0):

it's a pretty common thing,
someone more qualified then myself [already answered this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060995/jquery-validation-show-error-icon-next-to-control-and-error-summary-on-top/1447297#1447297).
good luck.